# Write int in one line to std::ofstream::write()

Tags: c++

I want to write binary to a file.

I am looking at the function std::ofstream::write().

It takes a pointer and how many bytes to write. Is there anyway I can do something simple like

```
ofstream.write(36);
```

instead of to do it in two lines like...

int out = 36;
ofstream.write((char*)&out , 4);

Comment: No there is no such way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

Since `write` uses a pointer, you need to provide an address. An easy way of doing it on a single line is to write a helper function, like this:

```
inline void write(ostream& o, int n) {
    o.write(&n, sizeof(int));
}
```

Now you can do it on one line:

```
int foo() {
    ofstream ofs("aaa");
    write(ofs, 36);
    write(ofs, 42);
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to do it in one line, not add extra lines :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, there's no way to make an address out of a literal without making a variable, so this is probably as close as it gets to a one-liner.

Comment: Just this week, I wrote the same function (template) :) , although I had to cast to char*. It was enough for me to keep the code cleaner.  Mind you that int is terrible to predict the number of bytes used in the stream.